# Relation between two functions with divisibility properties

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Given a positive integer $q$ and a finite set $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, define the functions
$$
f(q)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{\substack{n,m\in A \\ n-m=qk}}1 \quad \mbox{and}\quad g(q)=\sum_{\substack{n,m\in A \\ q|n-m}}1.
$$
I want to know if there any relations between the two functions. I think for instance it is true that $f(q)\le g(q)$, but I would like more explicit relations, maybe something like $f(q)=c g(q)$ where we can compute $c$ explicitely or at least bound it.

An example is for instance $A=\{1,2\ldots, 9\}$ and $q=1$. Then, $f(1)=36$ and $g(1)=81$. In this case $c=4/9 \lt 1/2$.

Comment: Is the index of the second sum a misprint? Otherwise, what does $n$ and $m$ range over?

Comment: Also, how did you compute your example? Since $q|n-m$ implies $q|m-n$, I would expect $g(q)$ to always be even for any $q$.

Comment: Sorry, the one with a typo was the first sum. Both sums range over integers $n,m$ in $A$. To compute the example, $g(1)$ is the sum over all $n,m\in A$ such that $1|n-m$. Since this is always satisfied, $g(1)$ is just $\#A^2=9^2=81$. For $f(1)$, the inner sum is over integers $n,m\in A$ such that $n-m=k$. If $k=1$, this quantity is $8$, if $k=2$, this is $7$, and so on. If $k=8$, that inner sum is $1$ and for $k\geq 9$, that sum is 0. Therefore $f(1)=1+2+\ldots+8=36$.

Comment: $f(q) $ simply counts the number of pairs $(n,m)$ where $q | n-m$ but also has the condition $n>m$ since $k$ has to be positive. $g(q)$ will also count all the pairs of the form $(n,n)$, and then for every $(n,m)$ (with $n\neq m$) that's in the sum you also have $(m,n)$, since if $q|n-m$ then $q|m-n$. So $f(q)=\frac{g(q)-|A|}{2}$.

Comment: There's one thing I don't understand though. Suppose again that $A=\{1,2,\ldots,9\}$. Then $f(10)=0$ and $g(10)=0$ because the condition $10|n-m$ with $n,m\in A$ is never satisfied. In this case the formula $f(q)=\frac{g(q)-\#A}{2}$ doesn't hold.

Comment: @Itachi It is satisfied whenever $n=m$, which happens precisely $|A|$ times, so $g(10)=9$ in your example. If you want to exclude the cases when $n=m$ from your sum then you calculated $g(1)$ incorrectly as it should be $g(1)=9^2-9=72$. In that case you have $f(q)=\frac{g(q)}{2}$.